# Remove first row contents in excel while export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, export-to-excel

I'm using the below code to export the gridview to excel. When I export the contents are appearing fine with no problems, but I am getting a control label like `System.WebControls.UI.Style` this in my first cell in `A1` cell.

Is there a way to hide this or remove and below is my code.

CS:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // ExportToExcel();
    if (ViewState["DashboardDetails"] != null)
    {
        lblError.Text = string.Empty;
        lblError.Style.Add("display", "None");

        grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.AllowPaging = false;
        DataTable dtHorizontalDashboard = (DataTable)ViewState["DashboardDetails"];
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HorizontalDashboard.xls");
        Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.AllowPaging = false;
            grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["DashboardDetails"];
            grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.DataBind();
            grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

            //Horizontal Cell
            TableCell cell0 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[0];
            cell0.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#9AD6EE");
            cell0.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Width;
            TableCell cell1 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[1];
            cell1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#96B060");
            cell1.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Width;
            TableCell cell2 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[2];
            cell2.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#96B060");
            cell2.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Width;
            TableCell cell3 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[3];
            cell3.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#96B060");
            cell3.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
            TableCell cell4 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[4];
            cell4.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C57838");
            cell4.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Width;
            TableCell cell5 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[5];
            cell5.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C57838");
            cell5.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Width;
            TableCell cell6 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[6];
            cell6.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C57838");
            cell6.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Width;       

           // Likely $ Impact & Overall Horizontal Utilization

            TableCell cell10 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[10];
            cell10.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#9AD6EE");
            cell10.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Width;
            TableCell cell11 = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[11];
            cell11.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#9AD6EE");
            cell11.Width = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Width;        
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = row.BackColor;
                    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            foreach (TableCell cell in grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.FooterRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.FooterRow.BackColor;
                cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            }
            Style style = new Style();
            style.BackColor = Color.White;    
            Response.Write(style);
            grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.RenderControl(hw);           
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());                 
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the first column or the first row (A1), just count the current row/column iteration and intercept the first and hide the A1 cell.

```
var rowCounter = 0;
var cellCounter = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdHorizontalSeatDashboard.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (rowCounter == 0 && cellCounter == 0) 
        {
            cell.Text = "";
        }

        cell.BackColor = row.BackColor;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
    }
    cellCounter = 0;
    rowCounter++;
}
```

Comment: The data gets exported from second row. Applying this would actually trim my first actual gridview row which means it will trim the headers. The problem actually occurs in rendering. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I see what you mean, so you just want to update/hide the contents of A1?

Comment: Updated, let me know if this is not what you're meaning

Comment: But I can still see that control as a label in A1 cell and it's not hidden.

Comment: You can still see it in the Excel export or when you're viewing as a web page?

Comment: I can still see it in the excel export in `A1` cell.

Comment: Hmmm seems very odd. Have updated answer, rather than `cell.Visible = false` try `cell.Text = ""`